# Doctrine_Pager returns wrong results with multiple groupBy columns

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine

I have Doctrine query setup with mySQL as database:

> ```
>   $q = Doctrine_Query::create();
>     $q->select('make.id, make.make, 
>     model.id, model.year, model.model')
>       ->from('Make make')
>       ->innerJoin('make.Models model');     
>     $q->groupBy('make.id, model.id');    // <-- this is where the problem
>     $q->orderBy('make ASC');
>     $q->setHydrationMode(Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_SCALAR);
>     $pager = new Doctrine_Pager($q, 1, 1);  // just want one result to prove the concept
>     $items = $pager->execute();
> ```

This executes this three queries (from mysql log):

> SELECT COUNT(*) AS `num_results` FROM (SELECT `m`.`id` FROM `make` `m` INNER JOIN `model` `m2` ON `m`.`id` = `m2`.`make_id` GROUP BY `m`.`id`, `m2`.`id`) `dctrn_count_query`
>
> SELECT DISTINCT `m3`.`id` FROM `make` `m3` INNER JOIN `model` `m4` ON `m3`.`id` = `m4`.`make_id` GROUP BY `m3`.`id`, `m4`.`id` ORDER BY `m3`.`make` ASC LIMIT 1
>
> SELECT `m`.`id` AS `m__id`, `m`.`make` AS `m__make`, `m2`.`id` AS `m2__id`, `m2`.`year` AS `m2__year`, `m2`.`model` AS `m2__model` FROM `make` `m` INNER JOIN `model` `m2` ON `m`.`id` = `m2`.`make_id` WHERE `m`.`id` IN ('33') GROUP BY `m`.`id`, `m2`.`id` ORDER BY `m`.`make` ASC

And the result set is

```
    array
        0 => 
            array
              'make_id' => string '33' (length=2)
              'make_make' => string 'Alfa-romeo' (length=10)
              'model_id' => string '288' (length=3)
              'model_year' => string '2010' (length=4)
              'model_model' => string '159' (length=3)
        1 => 
            array
              'make_id' => string '33' (length=2)
              'make_make' => string 'Alfa-romeo' (length=10)
              'model_id' => string '289' (length=3)
              'model_year' => string '2010' (length=4)
              'model_model' => string 'MiTo' (length=4)
        2 => 
            array
              'make_id' => string '33' (length=2)
              'make_make' => string 'Alfa-romeo' (length=10)
              'model_id' => string '290' (length=3)
              'model_year' => string '2010' (length=4)
              'model_model' => string '159 SPORTWAGON' (length=14)
```

The problem is with second query that returns make.id which is used in third query to select 1 make (Alfa-Romeo which has 3 models). What I want is to return NUMBER OF make/model combinations.

If I change number of items returned in Doctrine_Pager to 2, I get 33 rows (because from two selected makes Alfa-Romeo has 3 models and Audi (which is next) has 30 models.

Where I'm making a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You can not combine multiple columns in a single group by. Try this...

```
$q->groupBy('make.id');
$q->addGroupBy('model.id');
```

or a little more compressed...

```
$q->groupBy('make.id')->addGroupBy('model.id');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$table->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_QUERY_LIMIT, Doctrine_Core::LIMIT_ROWS);
```

http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language/en